# Parse ember Rest adapter hasMany relation ship ember-parse-adapter

Tags: ember.js, parse-platform

Hi I am unable to get hasMany relationship right in parse ember adapter here is my code.

```
   var newpost = this.store.createRecord('post', {
    text: 'mypost',
});
newpost.save().then(function () {
    var newcomment = this.store.createRecord('comment', {
        text: 'mycomment'
    });
    newcomment.set('post', this.store.find('post', newpost));
    newcomment.save();
})
```

My url Query parameters looks like this in chrome

```
    where[$relatedTo][object][__type]:Pointer
where[$relatedTo][object][className]:Post
where[$relatedTo][object][objectId]:2KdEkYmOGX
where[$relatedTo][key]:comments
```

and I get this error

```
{"code":102,"error":"wrong type of relation.  Expecting: , but recieved: Comment"}
```

my models are basic
Post

```
import ParseModel from 'appkit/models/parsemodel';

var post = ParseModel.extend({
  text: DS.attr('string'),
  comments : DS.hasMany( 'comment', { async : true } )
});

export default post;
```

comment model

```
import ParseModel from 'appkit/models/parsemodel';

var comment = ParseModel.extend({
  text: DS.attr('string'),
  post : DS.belongsTo( 'post' )
});

export default comment;
```

Comment: when do you get the error? on save?

Comment: yes on save 'newcomment.save();' My Post gets saved on parse.com new comment is not getting saved. the id "2KdEkYmOGX" mentioned above is id of Post saved